# Extending/changing status after traveling to the USA

Tags: usa, visa-extensions, deportation

Is there anything specifically to be concerned about as a visitor when extending the duration of stay while in the USA? Of particular concern are any repercussions if the extension of stay is denied. Would the visitor have to leave immediately?

Comment: This is pretty broad.  Can you narrow it down a bit?  Regular users of this site know that you are very knowledgeable about US immigration law, so it shouldn't be too hard for you to do.

Comment: @phoog I deliberately asked this question to alert people to the recent change in immigration policy. https://www.cbsnews.com/news/changes-to-federal-policies-pave-way-for-sudden-visa-denials-deportation/ .  I believe it has an impact on answers to previous questions here.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of that; thanks for alerting us to it.  I would perhaps ask the question more specifically still, perhaps something like "what are the consequences of omitting critical evidence in an application to extend visitor status?"

Comment: A permanent resident visa? What is with that news article?

Comment: @MichaelHampton trying to pack too much information into one sentence, I suppose.  One doesn't renew permanent residence status, by definition, but one can apply for it while inside the US, and such an application falls under the policy covered in the article.  The use of the word "visa" is incorrect in any case, since even for temporary visitors a successful application would not result in the issuance of a visa.

Comment: @phoog Actually my focus is on pointing out that immediately ones extension of status is denied, one is immediately put into deportation proceedings. It is a major game changer. I believe everyone already knows that omitting evidence is ground for denial so I am not focused on that.

Comment: @TheZealot but with the older policy omitting evidence would not have resulted in a denial but a request for evidence.  And "what are the consequences" doesn't exclude an answer mentioning deportation proceedings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new policy under the current administration, most immigrants who apply to extend or change status [are being put into deportation proceedings **immediately** the change of status is denied](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/changes-to-federal-policies-pave-way-for-sudden-visa-denials-deportation/). This was not formerly the case.

> A pair of policy memos circulated recently by U.S. Citizenship and
>   Immigration Services may pave the way for sudden visa denials and
>   referrals for deportation, immigration attorneys say.

Basically trying to get a one month visit extended by even two weeks can lead to you being put deportation proceedings immediately the extension is denied.

This started two weeks ago. To err of the side on caution, the recommendation is nobody on visitors visa should apply to extend status unless it is a dire medical condition or something similar. When ones period of stay is up just leave. Getting put in removal proceedings seriously jeopardizes your ability to ever visit again because it is a blot on your immigration record both in the USA and elsewhere.